# Accessing nested values in PHP json_encode

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I converted an array to JSON, how do I get the value of the slug from it?

```
{
  "230": {
    "term_id": 230,
    "name": "Executive Committee",
    "slug": "executive_committee",
    "term_group": 0,
    "term_taxonomy_id": 241,
    "taxonomy": "team_member_filter",
    "description": "",
    "parent": 0,
    "count": 1,
    "object_id": 1561,
    "filter": "raw"
  }
}
```

Of course the first value "230" is different for each instance. How do I access the "slug" value for each instance inside of my loop?

I originally had this array in `$variable`:

```
  Array ( 
   [230] => stdClass Object ( 
      [term_id] => 230
      [name] => Executive Committee 
      [slug] => executive_committee
      [term_group] => 0 
      [term_taxonomy_id] => 241 
      [taxonomy] => team_member_filter
      [description] =>
      [parent] => 0 
      [count] => 1 
      [object_id] => 1561 
      [filter] => raw 
   )   
)
```

Why does `$variable['slug']` not return anything?

Comment: Can you show the actual code that you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and then you can access like an array:

```
$items = json_decode($variable, true); // 'true' here makes the json an associative array
foreach($items AS $item) {
    echo $item['slug']; // because it is associative  you can access each value by name
}
```

This echos `executive_committee` for the JSON you provided above.

---

From the original array (`$variable`)you would do the same thing:

```
foreach($variable AS $item) {
    echo $item->slug; // because you have an object, not an array 
}
```

Comment: I was actually using json_encode from the original array because $item['slug'] was not returning anything.  How do I make the original array associative?

Comment: You original array was associative to begin with. If you'd like to edit your post above, adding your original array, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Cool - guess what? The same `foreach()` code will work! ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: ha, $item['slug'] is not returning anything for me.  It is inside of the default wordpress loop.  If I just print_r $items, the array for each post gets printed.  But as soon as I add ['slug'], I get nothing

Comment: It is because `slug` is nested within the array item. You have to loop through `$variable`.

Comment: That does not make sense to me. If I am already looping through each post with that array, I don't see what else there is to loop through

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$item->slug`?

Comment: You loop through the array(`$variable`) by its numbered pieces (like `230`). The numbered piece contains an item named `slug`. You could `echo $variable[230]['slug']` to get the slug in the piece numbered `230` for instance.

Comment: It is an associative array @PatrickQ, because of the `true` flag in `json_decode()`

Comment: That does not work.  Returns error 'Cannot use object of type stdClass as array'

Comment: @JayBlanchard I was going based on OP's original array, which contains objects inside (at least according to the updated question)

Comment: You don't have an array then, you have an object and you would have to use object notation: `$variable->230->slug`

Comment: @jay Yes! but how do i return that slug for all the posts objects...230,231,232 etc?

Comment: You loop through the object just as I do in the second (updated) example @JordanBarber